# Help creating a service, escaping binPath

Tags: windows-services, batch-file

I want to create a service and need to escape double quotes in the binPath. The path should be something like this: C:\path_to\service_executable.exe -i "path_to_config_file.conf"

Do I simply double up the double quotes? ie.

```
binPath= "C:\path_to\service_executable.exe -i ""c:\path_to\config_file.conf"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes after the EXE path is considered start parameters (-i "c:\path_to\config_file.conf"). They are specified in a separate field.

If you use Services.msc you can add it in "Start parameters" edit box.
If you use a MSI to install the service, you can use the "Arguments" column in [ServiceInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371637%28VS.85%29.aspx) table.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up copying the registry key of our production server and merging it on dev (they are essential mirrored). It turns out that didn't work either as the service doesn't show up in service console.

Comment: AFAICS, the "start parameters" are just for the current start, they are not saved permanently.